# Is httpPost too demanding to be used in an Android service?

Tags: android, http-post, android-service

I need my app to receive notifications, but my boss does not want to rely on Google Cloud Messaging so I will use httpPost in a background service instead for periodically check for new messages.

My question is: will that be too demanding for the battery and data consumption? Do you know a better option?

Thank you.

Edit:

This is an app for a delivery store. The messaging starts when you ask for something and ends when you receive the item. The message query will be every minute for about 10 or 20 minutes.

Comment: It depends. How periodically?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html

Comment: This link is great! (lol, and it recommends GCM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this would not seem like a good idea. The scenario you describe seems like a perfect fit for GCM. I would first try to convince your boss to reconsider. :)

"Polling" a server, even for a brief connection which transmits hardly any content, means the device must be woken (from a low power state) and the radio turned on, and it will *stay on* for a significant time. The impact on data consumption will probably be insignificant, but battery usage *will* be a concern.

In case it cannot be avoided, you should check [Minimizing the Effect of Regular Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html) section of the Efficient Downloads referenced by @CommonsWare in the comments.

Also, Reto Meier gave an [excellent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM) on this subject at the 2012 Google I/O. His [series on Efficient Data Transfers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSIB2pDvH3E) is also very informative. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: The client had a bad experience with parse, a PUSH server, so I couldn't convince him to rely on Google instead.
Anyway, the background service only activates 10 or 20 times to fetch new messages it stops when the deliver is done.

Comment: In the end, my boss told me to use parse.com. He must not know parse uses GCM